# Spark Cassandra connector - where clause

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am trying to do some analytics on time series data stored in cassandra by using spark and the new connector published by Datastax.

In my schema the Partition key is the meter ID and I want to run spark operations only on specifics series, therefore I need to filter by meter ID.

I would like then to run a query like: Select * from timeseries where series_id = X

I have tried to achieve this by doing:

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> rdd = sc.cassandraTable("test", "timeseries").select(columns).where("series_id = ?",ids).toJavaRDD();
```

When executing this code the resulting query is:

```
SELECT "series_id", "timestamp", "value" FROM "timeseries" WHERE token("series_id") > 1059678427073559546 AND token("series_id") <= 1337476147328479245 AND series_id = ? ALLOW FILTERING
```

A clause is automatically added on my partition key (token("series_id") > X AND token("series_id") <=Y) and then mine is appended after that. This obviously does not work and I get an error saying: "series_id cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal".

Is there a way to get rid of the clause added automatically? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver automatically determines the partition key using table metadata it fetches from the cluster itself.  It then uses this to append the token ranges to your CQL so that it can read a chunk of data from the specific node it's trying to query.  In other words, Cassandra thinks series_id is your partition key and not meter_id.  If you run a describe command on your table, I bet you'll be surprised.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. "series_id" is in fact the partition key (I am aware of it) and it is also the meter id. I just want to filter by the partition key. In other words I need SELECT * FROM timeseries where series_id = X. Is that not possible ?

Comment: Can you please post your schema?

Comment: CREATE TABLE timeseries (
  series_id bigint,
  ts timestamp,
  value double,
  PRIMARY KEY (series_id, ts)
)

Comment: I don't see meter_id in your schema; series_id is your partition key. The problem is querying by partition key would be pretty inefficient in Spark, because all your requests would go to the same node.  In fact your schema itself looks suspect, as all events for a given series would go to the same node (and its replicas). This is unlikely to result in an even distribution.

Comment: In the schema I call the meter ID "series_id". This schema works for me because I have many many series that are not too big (it is hourly data for 5 or 6 years). I need to run some aggregation only on some of them and I was thinking of doing it with Spark. Thanks for your help

Comment: If series_id is actually a specific meter (I used to work with utility meter data, so I'm assuming something similar), then it sounds like your Spark job is just analyzing a single meter. If that's not a lot of data, then 1) why are you using Spark, and 2) why not just pull in all meters and crunch all your numbers at once?

Comment: It is exactly utility meter data, but it is hourly. It is not a lot of data for a single meter but it is a lot of data altogether. I receive big chunks of data from time to time and I was thinking of processing only the new data (the old one would be already processed). It might not be too expensive though to process everything. I will try that and if does not work I will have a look at something else. Thank you!

Comment: Also, you can add a filter on `ts` if you just want a certain range of time. This may be what you're looking for.