# Spark Cassandra Connector - where clause

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to do a `select where` using `Datasax Cassandra Connector`, but I'm getting following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during preparation of SELECT "path" FROM "tracking"."user_page_action" WHERE token("user_id") > ? AND token("user_id") <= ? AND user_id = ?   ALLOW FILTERING: user_id cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal
```

I don't really understand why does the `connector` add the other restrictions.

This is how I'm trying to read:

```
spark.cassandraTable(keySpace,table).select(column).where(whereColumn + " = ?", whereColumnValue).collect()
```

and it is just like in their [documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md)

`user_id` is the `primary key` of the table and also I tried the `select where` in the terminal using `cqlsh` and it works.

I took a look at similar questions but they weren't helpful

[Dataframe where clause doesn't work when use spark cassandra connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047157/dataframe-where-clause-doesnt-work-when-use-spark-cassandra-connector)

[Spark Cassandra connector - where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994387/spark-cassandra-connector-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the spark-cassandra-connector added range restriction on the token. Typically, your query is split by the connector into several queries according to the token range to enforce that each query is executed against a replica, ensuring data locality.
In your case, you provide the full partition key with user_id=value (arguably, Spark is not the right tool in this case, but I don't know what your application is doing). There has been some discussion on the Spark-Cassandra-Connector project to fix that, I don't know if it happened.

However, if you switch to Cassandra 2.2 or 3 (I am assuming you are running Cassandra 2.1), Cassandra will accept the generated query (the one where the partition key is restricted by both equality and range). I tested it on 2.2.6 and 3.0.5.